# How do I make all the times in the database etc be in UTC and the whole view part be in the local timezone?

Tags: php, zend-framework

From an E-Mail I get 'Sun, 21 Jun 2009 20:21:13 +0200' as the time how do I make strtotime output the universal time for it? which would be 18:21:13? I want to have the view part in UTC+2 (at least right now should follow :)). How do I achive this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$ts = strtotime('Sun, 21 Jun 2009 20:21:13 +0200');
echo gmdate('D, d M y H:i:s'); // DATE_RFC822 without O
```

prints

```
Sun, 21 Jun 09 18:36:27
```

see http://php.net/gmdate